# How/where can I find replacements for these 'wheel bearing caps'?

Tags: hub, replacement, rear-wheel, bearings

I have started the restoration of a bike picked up from the bins. The bike has taken some abuse. The rear wheel axle was broken, same for the two "bearings" caps or dust seals. I am not sure how to name these. I am providing pictures here for illustration https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9xSC.jpg

It was really to get a replacement for the bearings and the axle, but that cap piece - maybe because of not knowing its name - I am not able to see it for sale anywhere. I am not sure how standard or custom these pieces are. The hub has no brand or logo. The bike is a carrera zelos if this helps.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I'd like to start a petition for smuggling that photo into an art exhibition.

Comment: Taking it as a compliment. I typically fail when trying to take a nice picture.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Metal dust shields would be the common name to the extent there is one. The usual protocol is to handle them with care and never remove them, because they're difficult to replace. The OEM hub manufacturers don't produce a vast number of different ones, so one option can be finding a bike shop with bins of used parts or dead wheels and trying to cannibalize some that match. Wheels Mfg does produce some cones that come with them, and there are generic axle kits that come with random sized ones, but getting it to work is all kind of a hail mary, especially if you need to order them. There are no standards as such for their ID, OD, depth, etc.

As long as they're not torn, working them back into shape looks possible from the pictures. They don't have to be pretty. One approach is finding a socket that's the right size and smacking them down flat again, then working the edges into shape with a hammer and the socket on the other side to act as a mandrel.

If you do find some to transplant, use a vise or suitably sized deep socket to provide support on the flat side, then gently tap them off the cone you found them on and onto the new one. You usually have to go back and adjust the depth a bit manually to make it the right height off the seal interface and prevent rubbing.

Comment: You may find replacement axles with cones and nuts etc where the cones have groves with rubber lips that close the gab between hub and cone to a minimum. Or do just as it was done like I remember we did when there were no such shields: Depending on conditions the hubs got serviced in 4-6 weeks turns.

Comment: Agreed- I'd start with a repair - using a vise and a suitable round-thing as a form.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Unfortunately I seem to have binned the other cap (which was in a worse state than the one in the picture). I am now thinking of popping by the bike shops/workshops nearby and asking if they have spares. Might be my last option before buying a new hub or wheel.

Comment: I had a look at ebay today and found this: https://ebay.us/j9FUdF An axle and a dust cap of diameter = 25mm I just measured the diameter on the one from the picture, it's not so round anymore but I am measuring ~28mm. Do you know if we are within tolerance for such piece?

Comment: Also the axle I shared sells with 2x7 bearings but the bike was using 2x9. Does it mean incompatibility?

Comment: Three mm different is too much. 7 is how many 1/4" go in a caged bearing for a hub that can take 9 loose.

Comment: Wen to a local bike workshop, showed them the wheel and I was told that they do not have any spares. They told me to use the closest washer I can find. I measured the diameter on the hub and it honestly looks like 25mm. I think I will buy one of these from ebay. Worst case scenario, not the biggest money loss of my life. @NathanKnutson

Comment: You can't properly clean the bearing without removing them. The trickiest are the one made of rubber with an exeternal metal ring (very easy to bend and super hard to fix). But they aren't hard to pull off, the trick is to pull them from several direction of the same time (thus NOT with using a screw driver as a lever). You can use 4 or more solid wires (e.g. from a cloth hanger) bend at the end, insert them all in the hole, place them in different part of the circonfenrence, and pull them all.

Answer (score 1):

Given the time it might take to track down a replacement, it might be cheaper to simply take measurements of your rim and buy a new replacement kit.

Comment: You mean buying a new rear wheel?